# How to make a precise parallel angled line (cut)

Tags: edges

Using Blender 3.5.1, total beginner.

I found numerous posts that seemed to be asking similar things, and yet so far I have not found a direct answer to my question. I'm aware Blender is not intended for precision work, and yet I find it hard to believe it can not do what I want. I'm sure I just don't know enough yet. What I want is so simple I don't even need pictures.

Make a cube. On a vertical face draw a line (cut) from an upper corner (vertex) to the opposite lower corner. If you remove the upper part you would have a wedge. Using that angled line, I want a second parallel line a precise distance away (-z axis, same face) from the first. The end goal is that second line is to be another cut so that removing the lower section of the cube results in a ramp with a specific thickness.

The part I can not figure out is how to make that second angled cut parallel and a specific distance apart. I want to enter numbers, not use a mouse.

Also, extruding and rotating a ramp shape would not give me what I want. The reason is I want to be able to define the X,Y and Z dimensions (of the cube), and have the angle and slope length automatically generated based on the results of going 'from top to bottom'. I experimented with manually calculating the slope length based on right angle triangles and doing it that way, but it's not what I want.

Comment: Hi. Actually a picture of what you want might help. For instance, do you want the -Z axis dimension to be the thickness of the ramp you want, or do you want the thickness of the ramp to be determined perpendicular to the edge that was created?

Comment: After making that post the thought occurred to me that mentioning the Z axis might confuse some folks. You responded before I got back to my PC. :)
Throw all the description out the window and simplify the Q like this:
How can I create a parallel line and numerically specify the (perpendicular) distance between the two lines?

Comment: you should definitely add some visual aid, like a pic or video (uploaded to youtube).

Comment: Scott, I suggest that you click Edit at the bottom left of your question and do what you suggest that we do. In other words, rewrite your question with what you have said in your comment. What you want would be far more visible than someone maybe seeing it in a comment. An image would still be helpful, especially if you are wanting the parallel lines on an angle. This would make it much clearer and easier for someone to possibly help you.